# Error en Android por duplicidad

Tags: android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este mensaje de error me aparece cuando intento ejecutar un programa de Android Studio.

Tambien me aparece en Event Log este mensaje:

> INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Split lib_slice_0_apk was defined multiple times

¿Que estare haciendo mal?

Comment: Hiciste lo que te dice el mensaje? Desinstalar la aplicación existente?

Comment: mira esta pregunta, le pasa lo mismo que a ti: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803518/split-lib-main-was-defined-multiple-times

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano Pues gracias. Ya lo he arreglado.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he arreglado.
Hay que ir a File->Settings y ahi desmarcar el icono que he subrayado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]